# A question about inverse closed subsets of $G \setminus \{e\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ is an inverse closed subset of $G\setminus\{e\}$. When does for all $a,b\in S$, $|Sa\cap S|=|Sb\cap S|$?

An obvious example here is when $S$ is a subgroup with deleted $e$. Then given $|S|=k$, we get $|Sa\cap S|=k-1$ for all $a\in S$.

Also, we can take $S=\{a,a^{-1}\}$ for every $a\in G\setminus\{e\}$. Then we have $Sa\setminus\{e\}=\{a^2\}$, $Sa^{-1}\setminus\{e\}=\{(a^2)^{-1}\}$, and our condition follows from $a^2\in S\iff(a^2)^{-1}\in S$.

**Motivation.** Given an inverse closed subset $S\subseteq G\setminus\{e\}$, we define the Cayley graph $\Gamma=\text{Cay}(G,S)$ such that $V(\Gamma)=G$ and vertices $a,b$ are adjacent iff $ab^{-1}\in S$. One may note that the set of neighbors $N_a$ of a vertex $a\in G$ is simply $Sa$. In particular, $\Gamma$ is $k$-regular, where $k=|S|$. The last statement also follows from the fact that Cayley graphs are vertex transitive (i. e. given vertices $a,b$, there is a graph automorphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(a)=b$). Now, we are interested in when a Cayley graph $\Gamma$ is locally $m$-regular, i. e. its induced subgraph $<N_a>$ is $m$-regular for every vertex $a\in G$. The vertex transitivity allows to restrict ourselves to the case $a=e$. Then we have $N_a=N_e=Se=S$. Thus for all $a,b\in S$, we want the sets $Sa\cap S$ and $Sb\cap S$ have the same cardinality $m$. So, my question is about properties of $S$ that are necessary or sufficient for this last condition.

Comment: ChatGPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations ([more](https://is.gd/YRoddz)). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "[hallucinate](https://is.gd/SUZiGn)" fake facts. Some extra examples: [1](https://bit.ly/483isiz), [2](https://bit.ly/3YRUlyX), [3](https://is.gd/WVmpdK), [4](https://bit.ly/45qeSNN), [5](https://bit.ly/44qRu1j), [6](https://is.gd/8UtFeo), [7](https://bit.ly/3KXlP0F), [8](https://bit.ly/3LpBgP4).

Comment: Recall that $S$ can't be a subgroup if it does not contain $e$.

Comment: @Deif sure, I mean we deleted $e$ from a subgroup. My bad English

Comment: Can you add some motivation / context for the question?

Comment: I doubt whether you can get a characterization. There are plenty of examples for which $Sa \cap S = \emptyset$ whenever $a \in S$, or equivalently $S^2 \cap S = \emptyset$. This condition is called "product-free". It is equivalent to the Cayley graph being triangle-free, or locally $0$-regular. If $G$ has order $n$ then almost all sets of size less than $n^{1/3}$ are product-free.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I've found a construction that for a given $m$ returns a group $G$ and inverse closed subset $S\subseteq G\setminus\{e\}$ satisfying $|Sa\cap S|=m$ for all $a\in S$, i. e. allows to get a locally $m$-regular Cayley graph $\text{Cay}(G,S)$. We need the following simple lemma.

**Lemma 1.** Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a subgroup of a finite group  $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{H}\setminus\{e\}$. Then for all $\mathscr{a}\in\mathcal{S}$, $|\mathcal{S}\mathscr{a}\cap\mathcal{S}|=|\mathcal{S}|-1$.

**Proof.** Note that $\mathscr{a}^{-1}\in\mathcal{S}$ and $x\mapsto x\mathscr{a}$ gives an injective function $\mathcal{S}\setminus\{\mathscr{a}^{-1}\}\rightarrow\mathcal{S}$ $\blacksquare$

Let us now choose groups $\mathcal{G}_1$,...,$\mathcal{G}_\mathcal{n}$ with subgroups $\mathcal{H}_1$,...,$\mathcal{H}_\mathcal{n}$ of order $m+2$. For $i=1,...,\mathcal{n}$, let $\mathcal{S}_i=\mathcal{H}_i\setminus\{e_i\}$. Put $G=\mathcal{G}_1\times...\times\mathcal{G}_\mathcal{n}$ and consider the sets $\mathcal{T}_i=\{(e_1,...,\mathscr{a},...,e_\mathcal{n}):\mathscr{a}\in\mathcal{S}_i\}$ for $i=1,...,\mathcal{n}$. Put $S=\mathcal{T}_1\cup...\cup \mathcal{T}_\mathcal{n}$. One can see that $S$ is an inverse closed subset of $G\setminus\{e_G\}$. Also, Lemma 1 implies $|Sa\cap S|=(m+1)-1=m$ for all $a\in S$.

Let me show an example of how this works. Say, we need a $3$-regular Cayley graph $\text{Cay}(G,S)$. Assume $G$ is a product of two cyclic groups whose order is a multiple of $3+2=5$. We may put $\mathcal{G}_1=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{G}_2=\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ and then take the subgroups $\mathcal{H}_1=\langle1\rangle$, $\mathcal{H}_2=\langle3\rangle$ of order $5$. Now $G$ is a $75$-element group $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ and we have

$\mathcal{S}_1=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$\mathcal{S}_2=\{3,6,9,12\}$

$\mathcal{T}_1=\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0)\}$

$\mathcal{T}_2=\{(0,3),(0,6),(0,9),(0,12)\}$

$S=\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(0,3),(0,6),(0,9),(0,12)\}$

Let us take a random element $a\in S$. Say, $a=(0,6)$. We have

$S+a=\{(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(0,9),(0,12),(0,0),(0,3)\}$

$|(S+a)\cap S| = |\{(0,9),(0,12),(0,3)\}|=3$